# JSP - make end of a src url a javascript variable

Tags: java, javascript, image, jsp

I have 'w', a javascript variable but I want to place it at the end of a src for an image.

So my image at the moment is:

```
<img class="chart" src="<%=IMAGEUrl%>">
```

the IMAGEUrl is defined in the jspf.

I want to add a variable from a javascript statement that I put on this same page so ...

```
<img class="chart" src="<%IMAGEUrl%>&variable=JAVASCRIPTVARIABLEHERE" >
```

thank you in advance

Comment: and this is not working?!

Comment: try `<img class="chart" src="<%=IMAGEUrl%>&variable=JAVASCRIPTVARIABLEHERE" >` equals was missing

Comment: how do i whack a JS variable in the middle of the src, everything else is jsp except the Java reference in the <%%>?

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to set this. the javascript code below can called when you want to change the image src.

```
function set()
{
var jsvar= " something" // javascript variable
var a = "<%=IMAGEUrl%>"+jsvar
document.getElementById("img1").src=a;
}
```

here is the image tag

```
<img class="chart" src=" " id="img1">
```